# Parameter of macro mixed with field of structure

Tags: c, macros

So I have macro like this:

```
#define some_macro(param1)    \
static some_struct_t struct = \
{                             \
    .param1 = param1          \
}
```

When I call this macro from main with direct value:

```
some_macro(50);
```

I got an error :

```
..\..\main.c(185): error:  #29: expected an expression
```

I found 2 ways to solve it, first was to declare const value within main and pass to macro and second to change name of parameter not be the same as in macro.

So it works but I do not what caused error. Any ideas?

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Rolled back. Do **not change vital parts the question once you got answers! Instead add corrections to the end.

Comment: Would you please stop editing! Your edit makes the answers loose context.

Comment: Sorry ! First time asking question.

In my code I did not use keyword struct for the name, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct` is a reserved word, you can not use it as a variable name

Change to something like:

```
#define some_macro(p1)                \
static some_struct_t valid_var_name = \
{                                     \
    .param1 = p1                      \
}
```

If you want to use the same name of the member (`param1`) as the name of your macro parameter you need to stop the expansion (using `##`) or you get `.50 = 50`

```
#define some_macro(param1)     \
static some_struct_t varname = \
{                              \
    .param##1 = param1         \
}
```

Comment: +1 for the trick. I'd strongly advice against anyone using it though. It's a lot cleaner to just pass the key and values to the macro

Comment: @quentin, @aec: we can also use [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs): `.param%:%:1 = param1`

Comment: Actually I was not asking for solution but explanation why that happens. You got any idea on this, knowing I did not use_struct_ for name of structure?

Comment: @Michal, of course but it is explained in the answer, the preprocessor replaces all occurrences of `param1` with `50` and you receive `.50 = 50`. Conclusion: you have chosen a bad name for your macro parameter, name it `p1` or something else than your member name.

Comment: Yes but again : is  the preprocessor that stupid? Does it not see operand " . " ?

Comment: [Take a look](http://www.jlekstrand.net/math/teaching/programming-course/unit-2/preprocessor/): Because expanding macros is simply a search-and-replace operation, a macro can technically contain anything. However, because it is just search-and-replace, the preprocessor knows nothing about the variables etc. so the macro may expand to something that makes no sense in the context.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with it.

`some_struct_t struct` is wrong. if some_struct_t is a *typedef* for a struct or a *define* for one, you need to do `some_struct_t myStruct` else `struct some_struct_t myStruct`

---

Another issue is, in the code your macro generates, you'll have something like the following (assuming the problem above is fixed):

```
struct some_struct_t myStruct = { .50 = 50 };
```

I believe you didn't intend to use `50` as an identifier :)

This may be more like what you want:

```
#define some_macro(key, value) \
struct some_struct_t myStruct = {\
    .key = value\
}
```

Or if you already know which variable you want to set:

```
#define some_macro(value) \
struct some_struct_t myStruct = {\
    .param1 = value\
}
```

Comment: Ok, of course I did not write it exactly like here using keyword struct for name of structure. And reagarding your answer, I thought that this may happend but I still do not know why. Can you give more detailed answer? I even tried to change macro to be exactly like you wrote but I got different error.

Comment: well, the macro definition still suffers from the 2nd error I pointed out. You are passing a numeric value to the macro and you're trying to use that as the identifier for a variable inside the struct

Comment: can you write what code you want generated by the macro? I gave an example of what your macro generates, lets compare it with what we want.

Comment: No this totally not what I want to do.

It goes more like this:

`typedef struct
{
    int param1;
}some_struct_t;

#define some_macro(param1)       \
static some_struct_t my_struct = \
{                                \
    .param1 = param1             \
}`

Comment: haha, then I will suggest this: `#define some_macro(value) struct some_struct_t myStruct = { .param1 = value }` . I don't think we have to keep `param1` as our macro parameter, do we?

Comment: In fact using the same name helps to understand part of bigger code but of course I can change it to something simillar. But my question why it crashes and not how to fix it, knowing now that problem is not with _struct_ . Can you expand answer why would it behave like `struct some_struct_t myStruct = { .50 = 50 };`

Comment: Look at the bit here: `= { .param1 = param1 }`. Simply replace every occurence of `param1` with `50`. What do you get?

Comment: I know but is the preprocessor that stupid? Does it not see operand " . " ? Is really answer that simple ? :)